# Number to words on javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new on Javascript.
I was asked to write a program that prompts the user to enter a number between 0-9. The
program should log the number in words.

```
const input = require('readline-sync');

let num1 = input.question("Enter a number between 0-9: ");
let a = num1.toString()

console.log(num1.toString)
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: A little hint, `var num1 = 1; console.log(num1.toString())` will print `'1'`

Comment: If you enter 1, it will give you an output as **`one`**. Won't it?

Comment: Like `console.log(['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five','six','seven','eight', 'nine'][num1])`?

Answer (score 0):

when you call `toString` you are trying to print the function, you need to invoke the function `toString()` to be able to print its returned value.

```js
const input = require('readline-sync');

let num1 = input.question("Enter a number between 0-9: "); 

let a = num1.toString()

console.log(num1.toString())
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this ?

```js
function myFunction(){
  var x = document.getElementById("username").value;
  console.log(x.toString());
}
```

```css
button{
  background:#0095ff;
  outline:noene;
  padding:10px;
  border:none;
  border-radius:5px;
  margin-top:10px;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="username">Enter Number:</label><br>
  <input type="number" id="username" name="username"><br>
</form>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```